# How to apply RLE() function in R with multiple conditions?

Tags: r, filter, rle

I have the following data:

```
dat <- structure(list(year = c(1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 
       1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1979L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 
       1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1980L, 1981L, 
       1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
       1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 1981L, 
       1981L, 1981L, 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 
       1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 
       1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 1982L, 
       1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 1983L, 
       1983L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 
       1984L, 1984L, 1984L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 
       1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 
       1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 
       1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 
       1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 
       1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 1985L, 
       1985L, 1986L, 1986L, 1986L, 1987L, 1987L, 1987L, 1987L, 1987L, 
       1987L, 1987L, 1987L, 1987L, 1987L, 1987L, 1988L, 1988L, 1988L, 
       1988L, 1988L, 1988L, 1988L, 1988L, 1988L, 1988L, 1988L, 1988L, 
       1988L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1989L, 1990L, 
       1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 
       1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1990L, 1991L, 1991L, 
       1991L, 1991L, 1991L, 1991L, 1991L, 1991L, 1991L, 1991L, 1991L, 
       1991L, 1991L, 1991L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 
       1992L, 1992L, 1992L, 1993L, 1993L, 1993L, 1993L, 1993L, 1994L, 
       1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 
       1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 
       1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 
       1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1994L, 1995L, 
       1995L, 1995L, 1995L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L, 1996L), mon = c(5L, 
       5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
       7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
       6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
       7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
       7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 
       5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
       6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
       7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
       7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
       6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 
       6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
       5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
       6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
       6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
       6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
       6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
       5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L), day = c(16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
       20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
       11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
       17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 
       27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
       11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 7L, 8L, 
       9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
       12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
       17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 
       30L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
       14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 
       27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
       17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
       5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 24L, 
       25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
       8L, 9L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 
       28L, 29L, 30L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 28L, 29L, 
       30L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
       17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 
       30L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 17L, 18L, 
       19L, 20L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 1L, 2L), phase = c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
       7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 
       8L, 8L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 
       7L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
       1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
       1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
       1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
       7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
       8L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
       4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
       6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
       7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
       8L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 
       8L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
       3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
       5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
       1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
       8L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Rainfall = c(23.2, 35.575, 37.4, 6.425, 
       10.275, 3.05, 50.075, 23.05, 2, 1.4, 3.325, 12.84, 0.68, 7.78, 
       0, 12.88, 91.48, 41.08, 4.48, 0, 0.26, 0, 2.32, 13.25, 64.5, 
       21.55, 82.175, 33.725, 48.95, 3.8, 16.875, 4.7, 7.7, 48.7, 25.275, 
       3.625, 0.075, 2.5, 0, 3.525, 0.725, 0.2, 0.625, 0.25, 2.85, 6.15, 
       10.675, 41.975, 24.975, 127.775, 86.225, 19.95, 1.725, 11.125, 
       0.075, 1.775, 5.825, 5.975, 18.125, 6.425, 3.725, 11.75, 13.975, 
       0.1, 1, 0.725, 4.775, 0.225, 2.625, 0.575, 13.375, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
       0, 0, 0, 0.825, 0, 0, 0.45, 2.2, 4.5, 0, 0, 0.05, 0, 0, 0.225, 
       0.975, 5.375, 9.1, 27.3, 47.7, 31.475, 4.8, 11.45, 3.15, 2.3, 
       14.975, 77.25, 112.225, 69.675, 27.625, 43.65, 34.85, 47.325, 
       65.725, 83.825, 29.525, 29.95, 12.575, 0, 3.2, 30.95, 26.25, 
       4.15, 0.025, 0.5, 0.375, 5.15, 3.525, 0, 0.55, 2.025, 10.525, 
       0.4, 0.05, 9.225, 0.2, 5.25, 0, 0.5, 1.3, 3.175, 7.825, 1.15, 
       3.475, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 4.275, 3.45, 0.075, 3.95, 23.525, 6.2, 
       5.7, 6.1, 4.975, 2.7, 0.95, 0, 0, 1.55, 37.525, 53.8, 26.275, 
       101.25, 81.825, 26.05, 6.4, 6.75, 0.65, 2.475, 2.7, 1.45, 0.775, 
       0.2, 5.8, 0.36, 0.02, 0.8, 2.64, 3.44, 26.8, 17.98, 3.88, 33.48, 
       8.08, 15.8, 11.52, 21.44, 31.18, 13.06, 12.92, 0.24, 4.48, 9.4, 
       4.24, 4.36, 2.34, 5.72, 16.56, 10.96, 24.12, 2.96, 28.48, 14.72, 
       6.32, 0, 0.3, 3.46, 0.62, 0.76, 0.46, 17.22, 10.92, 1.96, 2.92, 
       0, 0, 3.44, 3.86, 2.88, 0.72, 0, 0, 0.06, 1.62, 28.74, 0.64, 
       0, 0, 1.18, 0.42, 5.46, 3.56, 0.44, 0.48, 4.9, 1.48, 2.7, 19.94, 
       0.4, 7.28, 29.56, 8.72, 1.5, 2.32, 2.42, 4.62, 1.2, 13.88, 9.76, 
       26.32, 11, 23.8, 10.08, 17.04, 47.6, 15.22, 4.06, 60.3, 71.2, 
       16.54, 0.44, 0.68, 0, 0.88, 0.1, 0.04, 0.34, 0, 0.36)), row.names = c(NA, 
       266L), class = "data.frame")
```

There are four columns in this data: year, month, day, phase, Rainfall

I would like to:

(1) Count the number of cases when rainfall is below 5 mm/day for at least 3 consecutive days (length >= 3)

(2) and the start (first occurrence) of these consecutive days should have a phase equal to 1.

I have the following incorrect script:

```
 dat2<-subset(dat, phase == 1)
 countruns = function(x){
    rainfall_rle_df <- data.frame(unclass(rle(x$Rainfall < 5)))
    nrow(subset(rainfall_rle_df, lengths >= 3 & values == TRUE))
    }

 countruns(dat2)
```

This script gives me a value of 5, but this is incorrect. The correct answer for the whole data should only be 4.

So the problem is that this script ignores the starting phase of the consecutive days.

For example the year 1996 in the data above has the following values:

```
 year   month day phase Rainfall
 1996   6  28     8    0.100
 1996   6  29     1    0.040
 1996   6  30     1    0.340
 1996   7   1     1    0.000
 1996   7   2     1    0.360
```

The starting phase is phase 8 so this should not be counted.

The years that satisfied the above conditions should be 1983, 1984, 1991, and 1993.

Any suggestions on how I can do this in R? Or is there a better way to do this in R?

I have to put the script inside a function countruns().

I'll appreciate any help!

Comment: no @akrun.. I solved the one yesterday. I deleted the post from yesterday.

Comment: Can you show the expected output

Comment: @akrun, the expected output should be 4. My script above gives 5

Comment: is it grouped by 'year'

Comment: yes! it is grouped by year

Comment: Can you check the solution belwo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We create grouping column with `rleid` (from `data.table`) after grouping by 'year', then keep the groups where `all` values of 'Rainfall' are less than 5, `filter` the groups where the `first` value of 'phase' is 1, and do the frequency count (`n()`) in `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
dat %>% 
  # // create a Date column as it is easier to check for consecutive days
  mutate(Date = as.Date(paste(year, mon, day, sep="-"))) %>% 
  # // create a group with year
  group_by(year) %>%
  # // add more groups with rleid on logical vector
  group_by(grp = rleid(Rainfall < 5), 
           # // checks for difference between adjacent Date
           # // if the difference is greater than 1, cumsum increments by 1
           grp2 = cumsum(c(0, abs(diff(Date))) > 1), .add = TRUE) %>% 
  # // filter groups where all Rainfall is less than 5 and number of rows >= 3
  filter(all(Rainfall < 5), n() >= 3) %>% 
  # // filter the groups where the first value of phase is 1
  filter(first(phase) == 1) %>%
  # // get the frequency count
  summarise(n = n(), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  # // remove the columns that are not needed
  select(-grp, -grp2)
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#   year     n
#  <int> <int>
#1  1983     8
#2  1984    11
#3  1991     6
#4  1993     5
```

---

If we want to wrap it in a function, the `{{}}` does the `enquo` + `!!` (when we pass unquoted variable names as arguments to function esp for the column names)

```
f1 <- function(data, year, month, day, rainfall) {
        data %>%
           mutate(Date = as.Date(str_c({{year}}, {{month}}, 
                {{day}}, sep="-"))) %>%
           group_by({{year}}) %>%
           group_by(grp = rleid({{rainfall}} < 5),
                    grp2 = cumsum(c(0, abs(diff(Date))) > 1),
                .add = TRUE) %>%
           filter(all({{rainfall}} < 5), n() >=3 ) %>%
           filter(first(phase) == 1) %>%
           summarise(n = n(), .groups = 'drop') %>%
           select(-grp, -grp2)
     }
```

-apply the function

```
f1(dat, year, mon, day, Rainfall)
# A tibble: 4 x 2
#   year     n
#  <int> <int>
#1  1983     8
#2  1984    11
#3  1991     6
#4  1993     5
```

Comment: the output should only be 4? the "at least 3 consecutive days" condition is missing here.

Comment: sorry...4 is the correct answer. The output should be a number since I will put this inside a function countruns()

Comment: @Lyndz I added the condition, but the now the number of rows would be 2 for 1996

Comment: hmm..the years that satisfied the conditions should be 1983,1984,1991, and 1993. I just counted manually.

Comment: @Lyndz I think i got the issue

Comment: @Lyndz then what about 1996, which you showed as expected 4?

Comment: @Lyndz From the example showed, there are no gaps in the dates

Comment: It should not be counted since the start (June 28) of the consecutive days is phase 8 not phase 1.

Comment: @Lyndz In your post, it says `For example the year 1996 in the data above has the following values:`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219842/discussion-between-lyndz-and-akrun).

Comment: nice. How do I put this inside a function countruns()?